# Multi-variate cross-partial derivative of a inverse function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

I have an invertible mapping $y=f(x,\theta)$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^K$ with a scalar parameter $\theta\in\mathbb R$. Consider its inverse $x=g(y,\theta)$. I'm interested in the matrix $\partial^2g/\partial y'\partial\theta$. Is it possible to express it in terms of the derivatives of $f$?

For $K=1$, the answer (in the more general case of an implicit $f$) is given [here](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node33.html) but is there a generalization for $K>1$?

Comment: What is the meaning of the prime in $y'$? Have you tried just implicitly differentiating the equation $g(f(x,\theta),\theta)$?

Comment: Oh, I just meant to take a derivative of a column-vector with respect to a row-vector. Please ignore it.
I tried a bit but didn't succeed, with all the inverse matrices.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, we have
$$f(g(y,\theta),\theta) = y,$$
for all $\theta$. Then totally differentiating both sides w.r.t. $\theta$ yields
$$0 = D_\theta f(g(y,\theta),\theta) + D_x f(g(y,\theta),\theta) D_\theta g(y,\theta) $$
Or rearranging, we have
$$D_\theta g(y,\theta) = - D_x f(g(y,\theta),\theta)^{-1} D_\theta f(g(y,\theta),\theta) $$
You could then differentiate this whole mess w.r.t. $y$ and use various matrix derivative formulae (see [for example](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)) to get your answer, replacing any instances of $D_y g(y,\theta)$ with the usual formulae from implicit function theorem as needed.

Comment: From differentiating $I=D_x f(g(y,\theta).\theta)D_yg(y,\theta)$, you get $$0=\sum_k \frac{\partial^2 f_i}{\partial\theta\partial x_k}\frac{\partial g_k}{\partial y_j} +  \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial^2 g_k}{\partial\theta\partial y_j} + \sum_{k,\ell} \frac{\partial^2f_i}{\partial x_\ell\partial x_k}\frac{\partial g_\ell}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial g_k}{\partial y_j}.$$ With what stats posted, you can solve for the derivatives you want. You can write this matricially if you work with one component of $g$ at a time.

Comment: Oh yeah good point, I wrote my response too quickly. Changing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^K$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ with $y = f(x, \theta)$ with $f: \mathbb{R}^K \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^K$. Assume $f$ is invertible and $x = g(y, \theta)$ be the inverse with $g: \mathbb{R}^K \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^K$.

Let $v = (x', \theta)'$ be a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^{K+1}$. For notation, ake $v_x$ to be the first $K$ elements and $v_\theta$ to be the last element of $v$.

Define $\tilde{f}(v) = \begin{pmatrix}f(v_x, v_{\theta}) \\ v_{\theta} \end{pmatrix}$, so that $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^{K+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{K+1}$. Note that since $f$ is invertible, so is $\tilde{f}$. The inverse is given by
$$
  \tilde{f}^{-1}(w) = \begin{pmatrix} g(w_{x}, w_{\theta}) \\  w_{\theta} \end{pmatrix}.
$$

With some abuse of notation, you can see this by $f(f^{-1}(w)) = f(g(w), w_{\theta}) = (f(g(w))', w_\theta)' = w$

The jacobian of $\tilde{f}$ at a point $v$ can be written as:
$$
  \mathrm{J} \tilde{f} = \begin{bmatrix} 
  \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right] & \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \theta} \right] \\
  0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$

Assuming the jacobian of $f$ is invertible, then so is the jacobian of $\tilde{f}$ and so by the inverse function theorem, we have:
\begin{align*}
  \mathrm{J} \tilde{f}^{-1} &= \begin{bmatrix}
    \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right] & \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \theta} \right] \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \\ 
  &= \begin{bmatrix}
    \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right]^{-1} & 
    - \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right]^{-1} \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \theta} \right] \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}, 
\end{align*}
where the last equality comes from the inverse of a block upper-diagonal matrix.

The relevant matrix is $\left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right]^{-1}$ which is a function of $(x, \theta)$. From (59) in [the Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), the derivative with respect to $\theta$ is given by:
$$
  - \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right]^{-1} \frac{\partial \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right]}{\partial \theta} \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right]^{-1}
$$

Comment: Yes, but now do the second derivative the OP asked for!

Comment: Just added; from the matrix cookbook on the inverse of a matrix

Comment: I do not believe that is a valid formula to use in this situation. That is just the formula $d(g^{-1}) = -g^{-1}dg\,g^{-1}$ for any matrix function. But the chain rule complications here are being ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem @TedShifrin. We have that 
$$
\left[ Jg \right](f(v)) = [\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} (x, \theta)]^{-1}
$$
which doesn't involve chain rule? I could be missing something!